# mongodb slave "Authentication failed"

Tags: mongodb, slave

when trying to connect to a slave i get an error: "Authentication failed"

master:

> mongod.exe --auth --dbpath xxx --master --keyFile xxx

slave:

> mongod.exe --auth --slave --source xxx:xxx --keyFile xxx --dbpath xxx

master works ok and the slave is synced too
mongo 3.4.6

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/ ?

Comment: these ones: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/master-slave/

Comment: Where do you see the "Authentication failed" message -- when logging in as a user or in the MongoDB server logs? Note: the master/slave topology has been deprecated since MongoDB 3.2 (and removed in MongoDB 4.0). I'd recommend using a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) for reliability and a future upgrade path.

Comment: I thought of that, but my slave is on a computer without a public ip. Will the replica set work in such configuration?